# Itinerary issue , will my uk tourist visa get rejected?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I’ve applied for uk tourist visa recently but the travel agency I used was careless and wrote wrong sur name of my flight bookings and booked a hotel in Luton while my itinerary says I’ll be travelling I. London (hotel too far )

Will that lead to a rejection? I’m really worried , unfortunately I didn’t see the mistake until after submission

Answer (score 2):

The UK does not require flight / hotel bookings when considering Visitor visa applications - see section 4 https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

IMHO therefore the travel agent’s mistake should not be a reason for rejection, although it does indicate that they don’t understand the UK visa application process. Luton is commuter-distance to London so the mistake isn’t totally out of line with your itinerary, assuming the ECO even looks at the booking.